# What is the different between getting DOM via id and class

Tags: jquery, dom

I've got a question while using jQuery(1.8.3) getting DOM.

```js
$(function() {
  //method 1
  var $y = $('.u')['0'],
    $n = $('.u')['1'];
  $y.click(function(e) {
    alert('hello y');
  });
  $n.click(function(e) {
    alert('hello n');
  });

  //method 2
  var $yid = $('#y'),
    $nid = $('#n');
  $yid.click(function(e) {
    alert('hello yid');
  });
  $nid.click(function(e) {
    alert('hello nid');
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- method 1 -->
<button class="u">yes</button>
<button class="u">no</button>
<br>
<!-- method 2 -->
<button id="y">yesid</button>
<button id="n">noid</button>
```

[code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2fqkzb3/3/)

I don't know why I can't use "method 1" to make click event works, I think it is something fundamental that I've missing, can someone give me advices?

Comment: Its better to use function `.each` when you are iterating all elements with specific class. Without [0] selectors...

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not please add a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.u')[0]` returns dom object not jQuery object. `click()` handler only works with jQuery object, so use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to get jQuery object.

```
var $y = $('.u').eq(0),
    $n = $('.u').eq(1);
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/f2fqkzb3/10/)**

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'll google for the keywords you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

While using `.u` for selection you will get an array dom object. As per your code to make it as a jQuery object you have to again select it like

```
$($('.u')['0'])
$($('.u')['1'])
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f2fqkzb3/11/)**

Comment: I get something from your  and Pranav's answers,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting something by `class` will return a different kind of item than selecting something by `id`.

Imagine that selecting something by `class` returns a box (an array) that contains everything with that class in it. Then imagine that selecting something by `id` just returns the item with that `id`.

If you select something by class then you'll still get the box (array) for "all your doms of this class" even if there were just 1 dom item with the class.

using the `.eq()` function in jquery can give you the first, or n'th item of the class.

given the html

```
<div class="myDiv" id="myId"></div>
```

The jquery script

```
$(".myClass").eq(0)
```

selects the same thing as

```
$("#myId")
```